# What's a reasonable number of Uniform tops to provide employees

Tags: management

How many uniform tops are reasonable to have for women working with small kids?

Comment: I feel like there's some context missing here. Is this about washing the uniforms? And what does "working with small kids" mean? For example, a nurse might require more uniform tops for health reasons.

Comment: From experience 3-4 is the normal number for jobs where the chances of getting a bit dirty exists. Logic is one wash a week plus a spare just in case. But if they're fingerpainting and stuff like that then overalls or aprons are a good idea. Pretty standard stuff in many jobs even without small kids. Most places I've worked uniform is employee responsibility to wash. Overalls/aprons the business responsibility and they stay onsite.

Answer (score 4):

How often do you think it is reasonable to ask your employees to do laundry?  Keep in mind your employees may not have a washing machine at home (they may live in apartments, or they may use coin laundry) so loads of laundry may equate to additional expenses.  If you had to pay $5 for a load of laundry (including washing and drying), how often would you want to do it (and also take the time to do it not just the money)?

Give your employees a reasonable number of uniforms so they don't have to do laundry an excessive amount or wear dirty uniforms to work.  A good number is probably at least equal to the number of work days per week; doing laundry once a week is not an unreasonable ask, although that's a bare minimum and hopefully you could be more generous than that.

Comment: For "working with small children", you'll likely want 3 times that, just to cover the week.  All sorts of things can happen to your clothes when working with small children.

Comment: Should the company do the laundry. Have a lot of them in various sizes. Change on site